# JPanel location issues

Tags: java, swing, jframe, location, jpanel

I have to create a GUI and I'd really like to set a background to it.
In order to do this, I've created a class called "Backround" where I'm using the paintComponent method. I gave it the file I want to set on the background and it worked.

Here is my Background class :

```
public class Background extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        try {
                Image img = ImageIO.read(new File("./fond.jpg"));
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
  }               
}
```

However, once the image is on the background, the panels that were on my frame are not anymore in the same location and I've really no idea how to fix that and still haven't found any relevant topics about this.

Here is a quote of my class where I'm describing the GUI :

```
    this.setContentPane(new Background());

    this.setTitle("Arena");                                     
    this.setSize(800, 500);                                     
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);                           
    //this.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    //this.setLayout(null);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        

    this.setVisible(true);                               


    // ******************************************** PANEL 1 ******************************************

    Panel P1 = new Panel();
    this.add("NORTH", P1);
    P1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    P1.add(new Label ("Joueur 1"));
    P1.add(new Label ("Action"));
    P1.add(new Label ("Joueur 2"));
    //P1.setVisible(true);


    // ********************************************* PANEL 2 ******************************************


    Panel P2 = new Panel();

    P2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    P2.add(Liste1);

    // Boutons
    Button B1 = new Button("FIGHT");
    P2.add(B1);
    Button B2 = new Button("HEAL");
    P2.add(B2);

    P2.add(Liste2);
    this.add("WEST", P2);
//  P2.setVisible(true);
```

Furthermore, when I remove the call to my Background constructor, the panels are getting back to their inital locations.

I hope you could help me or redirect me!

Thanks!

Antoine Sbert

Comment: Have you tried calling repaint(); and revalidate(); ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't seem to change anything...I'm going to try again to see if it may fix it!

Comment: you are adding WEST - NORTH but it doesn have a layout borderlayout - you need to clear that: frame has a certain layout then you add to it

Comment: you just need to get your things straight

Comment: nice! it works! thank you very much!

Comment: however, I don't succeed in reducing the size of my panels. Is there any class or method I should know for that?

Comment: @AntoineSbert I believe Flow Layout automatically sizes each panel to fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make sure you call `super.paintComponent` before performing any customer painting
2. Don't load resources (like images) from with in the paint method, this will have an impact on the performance of you program
3. `JPanel` by default use a `FlowLayout`, but you never change the layout after you apply the `Background` panel as the `contentPane`. After calling `setContentPane`, use `setLayout(new BorderLayout())` or apply the layout in the classes constructor (at the same time when you load the image)
4. Make sure you call `setVisible` last, after you've established the basic UI

Comment: thank you! I've finally figure out how to make my GUI looks as I wanted it to. If you could send me some other way to load ressources, I'd apprciate it!

Comment: Preload them, maybe in the constructor instead?

Comment: That what I've done,by overloading the paintComponent constructor.

Comment: `paintComponent` is not a constructor, it's a method, which will get called hundreds of thousands of times every runtime ... you really, really, really don't want to be trying to load the same image that many times

Comment: Ok I get it tank you!